# How to fix "cannot open file 'Test.py': [Errno2] No such file or directory"?

Tags: python, path

I tried to run a python script which does not exist in current folder, for example

`C:\>python Test.py`

> python:can't open file 'Test.py':[Errno2] No such file or directory

I have to specify the absolute path c:\testdir\test.py to make the command workable.

`c:\python c:\testdir\Test.py`

I tried to append "c:\testdir" into Env argument 'PATH', but it still doesn't work.

i want to use the filename rather than the entire path, 
c:\python Test.py
can i make it happen?

Comment: Well, yea, just `cd C:\testdir`. Then, you can `python Test.py` to your hearts content

Comment: thanks！so, it is no way to run the file in different folder if i doesn't specify the entire path?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I suspect PATH variables would be necessary, however I don't think that is really worth doing. It's a bit of a hassle, and not really even necessary.

Comment: yes, i understand your meaning, but in my specific scenario, i would like to do this.anyway, thanks for help answer it.

Answer (score 0):

That means you're not currently in `C:/testdir` (you're in `C:`). Enter `cd C:\testdir` in your terminal to move to that directory (`cd` = **c**hange **d**irectory).

The reason you have to specify the entire path while out of the folder is because even if you're not in the folder that you're trying to reference, you can still use its path to reference it.