# script is on PATH, yet python3 script fails: no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, command-line, path

```sh
dag@Arokh:~$ source /home/dag/.bashrc
dag@Arokh:~$ echo $PATH
/home/dag/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dag@Arokh:~$ python3 /home/dag/.local/bin/facemorpher --version
Face Morpher 1.0
dag@Arokh:~$ python3 facemorpher --version
python3: can't open file 'facemorpher': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Adding the directory to `PATH` doesn't seem to help. How can I make `python3 facemorpher` work from any directory?

Comment: I guess yours would properly be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840939/how-to-fix-cannot-open-file-test-py-errno2-no-such-file-or-directory instead but it doesn't have an upvoted answer. Long story short, don't type `python3 facemorpher` when the script you want to run should be run simply with the command `facemorpher`

Comment: AH, indeed, facemorpher --version executes. Thank you for your help! So, should I delete the question, or leave it as is?

Comment: It seems it could be helpful to reopen the question and add the solution of omitting 'python3' when executing without full path - it is useful info and hard to find the answer to unless you already know it. Especially since examples online execute it with 'python'. The duplicate you've indicated has a very situation-specific title and description, *and* no explanation on how to run the script without the path. Also, this is not a duplicate of what it's marked as atm.

Answer (score 0):

`python3` pays no attention to the `PATH` variable when looking for scripts. This variable controls where the *shell* looks for executables.

So what *should* work now, provided the script has executable permissions and a valid shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as its very first line, is that simply

```sh
facemorpher
```

without `python3` in front should run the script. Perhaps this is actually what you want and need.

The `python3` command without any options expects a file name parameter; there is no simple way to make it look for a file which doesn't exist in the specified directory (which is the current working directory if the filename doesn't have an explicit directory part; this is how the operating system resolves relative file names, and should probably not be messed with for an individual command). For further details about this, perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)

For the record, `chmod a+x path/to/scriptname` adds execute permission to the script for all users on the system, and the path in the shebang after `#!` should point to your Python interpreter's full path, or the full path to a utility like `env` which finds it on your `PATH` and executes it based on just the command name (here, `python3`; but on some systems, the Python interpreter executable's file name is just `python`, or more broadly whatever the system's owner decided to name it).